# Calculating deltas in Apache Beam using Stateful processing

Tags: java, apache-beam

I have a bunch of input streams that may send updates over time. If an update occurs I need to calculate the delta to be able to process it further. In short:

```
Input: 10 -> State: 10, Output: 10
Input: 12 -> State: 12, Output:  2
Input:  5 -> State:  5, Output: -7
```

I read [stateful processing](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/02/13/stateful-processing.html) and [timely processing](https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html) in order to gain understanding in how to work with this kind of state in an Apache Beam application, but what I can't figure out is:

1. Is there a 100% guarantee that my stateful DoFn won't process items with the same key in parallel?
2. I want to make sure that the state is persisted when my application restarts or fails, so that I can start with the correct initial value. How do I make sure my DoFn "cleans up" (persists to a datastore) before shutting down?

For #2 I was wondering if this might work when using global windows:

```java
public class Delta extends DoFn<KV<String, Integer>, Integer> {
    @StateId("state")
    private final StateSpec<ValueState<Integer>> stateSpec = StateSpecs.value();

    @TimerId("timer")
    private final TimerSpec timerSpec = TimerSpecs.timer(TimeDomain.EVENT_TIME);

    @ProcessElement
    public void process(ProcessContext context,
                        BoundedWindow window,
                        @StateId("state") ValueState<Integer> state,
                        @TimerId("timer") Timer myTimer) {
        // Assign the timer to the end of the current window, which is a global window
        // Not sure if this always triggers when the application stops...
        myTimer.set(window.maxTimestamp());

        int value = context.element().getValue();
        int acc = getOrInitialize(state.read());
        int delta = value - acc;
        state.write(value);
        context.output(delta);
    }

    @OnTimer("timer")
    public void onTimer(OnTimerContext context,
                        @StateId("state") ValueState<Integer> state) {
        // Persist value of state here
    }

    private int getOrInitialize(Integer a) {
        // Get initial value of state here
        return (a != null) ? a : 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. I don't think your timer approach would work without any configuring any `BoundedWindow`. `@StartBundle`/`@Setup` and `@FinishBundle` should be better places for recovery and checkpoint. I don't recommend `@Teardown` because it's not guaranteed to be called.

Comment: I’ve been looking into the documentation for `@StartBundle` and `@FinishBundle` but it looks like they don’t support the `StateId` annotation to provide access to the state.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that. One workaround is to use an external database (e.g. Cloud Datastore, Cloud BigTable etc), but at that point you probably don't need to use Apache Beam at all. Another workaround is to use processing timers to checkpoint values. However, when the pipeline is restarted, not everything will be guaranteed to be checkpointed

Comment: I am actually planning to use Cloud Datastore to save the "current" value for each key. The problem I'm trying to solve has to do with race conditions occurring when one of our sources publishes a lot of updates at once. Why would I not need to use Beam when working with a database?

Comment: Datastore supports transactions: you can do read, calculate the delta and store new value in a transaction. If commit fails, there needs to be some retry logic. A simple web service can do that. You don't necessarily need to use Apache Beam. It doesn't hurt if you still want to use it.

Comment: Well the delta calculation is only a small part of a bigger pipeline, which unfortunately isn't something a web service can handle easily.

Answer (score 1):

1. Stateful processing is parallelized per key and window. Two elements for the same key but different windows can be processed in parallel. But your elements are all in the global window, so it is the same as per-key parallelism in your case.
2. Using timers is the right idea to flush your state. An event time timer at the end of the global window will never fire during normal pipeline operation, but will fire in a "drain" scenario in which all watermarks are moved to infinity. Drain is a feature of Cloud Dataflow that has been proposed as a portable concept across Beam, but you should look into whether your choice of runner has such a feature.